# Excel and Office.js access to CustomXml Part

Tags: excel, angular, office-js

Our Web Application stores/creates documents for clients.  Our clients download these document which contain custom tagging parts which are client specific and stored the customxml part in both Excel and Word documents.  We currently use an activex ribbon bar app that retrieves these parts and displays them for the user.  This allows them to access these parts to be inserted into the document by the ribbon bar app.

We then sought a better and more compatible way to accomplish this to get away from activex but also allowing clients that use older version of Word and Excel to continue to use the activex control.

Microsoft assisted us in creating our Word Addin that used Angular and Office js to accomplish this in MS Word.

Now we need to replace our Excel ribbon bar app.  I am leading the creation of this tool and found that Excel API currently does not allow access CustomXml Part in the document structure.

1. Is there any way to access the customxml part in Excel?
2. Is there any plans to allow access in a future release.
3. Can you recommend a best practice for storing and retrieving these part if the first two question are no.

We are using Angular2 and Office.js to create the new addin.

Comment: I am using 1702 Build 7870.2020.   I am using Office.js version Version: 16.0.7819.1000 the newest I can find and still cannot see the customXml part in my add in.  I am using Angular 2.0.0, TypeScript 2.2 in the add in.  I am building off the example at: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/building-an-office-add-in-a9d506cd

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is coming soon in API set 1.5 : see the open spec details here
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec/reference/excel

Answer (score 0):

As Charles mentioned, Custom XML parts API will be available as part of Excel API #1.5 set. 
If you have 1702 build of Excel, you can test this out now. See [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets.md) for details.

Comment: Insider Fast 1704.8001.1001 still reports that IseSetSupported('ExcelApi',1.5) is False which is in conflict with the GitHub Dpcumentation

Comment: How do I get access the the 1702 build

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/215f5d35490c943cc06c29b98357ba8cb034ec81/docs/develop/install-latest-office-version.md) talks about getting the latest version.

Comment: Also, The 1.5 requirement set support won't be positive until this comes out of Beta. Anticipating this to be in GA state by 1703 build. However, that shouldn't stop you from testing this our of beta.

Comment: As I mentioned in my above update I am still not seeing the customXml part.